# Is there a way find to find out if a software keyboard is shown?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

My actual `UITextField` control is embedded many layers down in an external library. Therefore I am unable to detect if it is being edited by calling

`control isFirstResponder`.

Is there another way to detect if the software keyboard is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try setting up a listener for notifications such as "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification". In the userInfo for the notification you can get the bounds for the keyboard and thus determine if it is visible (on screen) or not. Look in UIWindow.h.